# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

this error appear

Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

for this statement in my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" id=@string.Format("radio"+     (item.Id).ToString()) class="css-checkbox9 all_check" value="@item.Id" />
<label for=@string.Format("radio"+ (item.Id).ToString()) class="css-label9" checked="checked">&nbsp; </label>
```

can anyone help me ????

Comment: Why on earth are you using `String.Format` for that? Aside from that issue there's no speech marks on your `for` and `id` properties

Comment: I want to make concatenation between the string "Radio" and @item.Id

Comment: Right... so why would you format, as shown in the answer below, `for="@("radio"+ item.Id)"` works fine as concatenation

Comment: it resulted this error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

Comment: and I tried another solution ::<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" id="radio+ @item.Id" class="css-checkbox9 all_check" value="@item.Id" />
                                    <label for="radio+ @item.Id" class="css-label9" checked="checked">&nbsp; </label>                                
                                  but it resulted this error : The best overloaded method match for 'System.Tuple.Create<object,int>(object, int)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

Making a few changes to your code, the '+' operation is sufficient for concatenation, so i have removed `string.format()`. Additionally i have also added the missing `""` to wrap the httpAttributes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" id="@("radio"+  item.Id)" class="css-checkbox9 all_check" value="@item.Id" />
<label for="@("radio"+ item.Id)" class="css-label9" checked="checked">&nbsp; </label>
```

Comment: it resulted this error:  Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

Comment: Is your 'Id' not an `int`?

Comment: try substituting item.Id with 123... and if that works, there is something wrong with your model. <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" id="@("radio"+  123)" class="css-checkbox9 all_check" value="123" />
<label for="@("radio"+ 123)" class="css-label9" checked="checked">&nbsp; </label>

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Id is int , but my model consists of two classes as properties , because i want to deal with 2 models in one view

Answer (score 0):

You can do what CodeReaper said or, if you want to maintain the `string.Format`, try this:

```
<label for="@string.Format("radio{0}", item.Id)" class="css-label9" checked="checked">&nbsp; </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" id="@string.Format("radio{0}", item.Id)" class="css-checkbox9 all_check" value="@item.Id">
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the result was this error:
The best overloaded method match for 'string.Format(string, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What's the type of your item.Id property?

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model)
{ }

Comment: but my model consists of two classes as properties , because i want to deal with 2 models in one view

Comment: But what is the type of Id property? Is this a string, integer, ...?

Comment: the type of Id property is class

Comment: Maybe you should override the method ToString of that class. Please show us the definition of the Id class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try string.Concat

Like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" id=@string.Concat("radio", (item.Id).ToString()) class="css-checkbox9 all_check" value="@item.Id" />
<label for=@string.Concat("radio", (item.Id).ToString()) class="css-label9" checked="checked">&nbsp; </label>
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0023: Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

Answer (score 0):

You have probably defined your Id "property" as method:

```
public string Id() {
    return myId;
}
```

You have to either make Id a property...

```
public string Id {
    get { return myId; }
}
```

... or use the parenthesis in your concatenation:

```
id= "radio" + item.Id()
```